# JavaPoet : How to add a field of type class , but I have only the class name, not the class?

Tags: java, javapoet

```
String fieldName = (fieldchild.getAttribute("Name")); //gives field name : opcode

String fieldCustomID = (fieldchild.getAttribute("ID")); //gives id: 2022

String classTypeofField = IdNameMappingList.get(fieldCustomID).toString(); //give class name OpCodeClass

FieldSpec fieldSpec = FieldSpec.builder(**some code**, fieldName)
                                                        .build();
```

**Should give something like** :

```
OpCodeClass opcode;
```

Any other work around is also appreciated.

Comment: You don't need the actual class, but you do need its _fully qualified_ name (e.g. "org.package.OpCodeClass") as JavaPoet must also generate an import statement for the class. With the package and class names, you can create a `ClassName` object to pass to the `FieldSpec` builder. If you're sure you don't need the import (e.g. your generated class is in the same package as all of the opcode classes) you can write the field as a literal without using FieldSpec. Another possibility would be to [search the class via reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/520328/1110381) based on its name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `ClassName.get("com.company.app", classTypeofField)`, replacing the package name with that of the class.

Comment: Thanks. That helped.